# Little glitch in MnSymbol

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, bugs

MnSymbol uses a few symbols from the text font, like `\dagger`, in math, and does so using the definition

```
  \ifx\Mn@Bold\math@version
    \text{\bfseries#1}%
  \else
    \text{\mdseries#1}%
  \fi}
```

Using `\text` here gets daggers to be set in italic if in, say, a theorem statement styled in italics, and that looks somewhat strange.

Adding an `\upshape` inside the `\text` fixes that.

I think that the package is somewhat frozen, but still :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that a correct definition would be

```
\textnormal{\ifx\Mn@Bold\math@version\bfseries\fi#1}
```

Just do

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\Mn@Text@With@MathVersion[1]{%
  \textnormal{\ifx\Mn@Bold\math@version\bfseries\fi#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

after loading `MnSymbol`.